# What does "match us in the market" mean in the context of transferring shares between brokers?

Tags: brokerage

I requested my company broker to transfer shares to my private broker and got a letter saying:

*We are reaching out to your broker to **match us in the market** so we can complete your transfer*

I asked them to explain what does that mean *match us in the market*.

The second reply was:

*Our records show that your broker did match us in the market to receive your shares.*

I am still curious what does it mean to *match in the market* in this situation?